# Core Data context not saving while trying to update (in Swift)

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8

I'm trying to update a Core Data set following on from a query (an update). For some reason, the code does not seem to be saving, no error is being thrown, and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code extract:

```
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

if itemId != nil {
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"CheckListItem")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"itemId == '\(itemId!)' ")

    var queryResults:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if queryResults.count > 1 {
        CLAlog("DSF-updateChecklistItem-update: Item ID Provided, but a singluar item not found in Core Data", 1)
        abort()
    }

    // Update Existing Item
    queryResults[0].setValue(itemList["itemTitle"]!, forKeyPath: "itemTitle")
    queryResults[0].setValue(itemList["itemDescription"]!, forKeyPath: "itemDescription")
    queryResults[0].setValue(itemType, forKeyPath: "itemType")

    //queryResults[0].setValue(itemList["itemDisplayOrder"], forKeyPath: "itemDisplayOrder")

    var contextError: NSError? = nil
    context.save(&contextError)
}
```

Any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the variable `contextError` for a possible error? The `save` method returns boolean, then you can print the error if it is false.

Comment: Yes, I have. The error variable is returning nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the type of queryResults var from NSArray to AnyObject as follows:

```
var queryResults:[AnyObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
```

Check that you are getting the right results on queryResults and check also that the values you are setting are not nil.

```
println(queryResults[0])
println(itemList["itemTitle"])
```